# Gamil API get information from a wrong account

Tags: api, gmail, gmail-api

I met a weird situation.
I am following the tutorial from below link  to retrieve information `https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name`

In my browser, I login in gmail of account A, but in the program I am using client_serect.json from Account B, also, I am using Account B as userid. However, When I test it, the program actually get and display the information of Account A. How can I get the information from Account B???

Comment: Problem Solved. Just have to log in the right gmail account on the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `client_secret.json` only contains the information that identifies your application at Google.

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "[[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]]",
    "client_secret": "[[YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET]]",
    "redirect_uris": [],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

You don't need to get a separate one for each user.

You need to store the `access_token` and potential `refresh_token` of each user, and use them separately.

Read [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)  on how this can be implemented.